# How to Parse JSON Response in JAVA

Tags: java, json

Im having trouble retrieving the temperature from the json code below using java. I'm able to retrieve the location but when I try to get the temperature i'm receiving the error `JSONObject["temp"] not a string.`

Comment: You should first worry about managing your resources correctly... You close none of them. Sure, it's only a `main` but start and get the basics right.

Comment: Use a library like fasterxml Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: The response is from an API request. I cant modify the resources

Comment: `temp` is not a field of the root object, but in `main` property

Comment: @fge what do you mean i close none of them? it says its valid json file using http://www.jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your function to `.getDouble` temp is not returning as a string value type.

So ıt should be like:

> obj.getJSONObject("main").getDouble("temp")

I edit the answer.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I never thought of using a double. I just presumed all data would be returned as a String.

Comment: great. you should select this as answer.

Comment: will do...it wont let me select the answer straight away

Answer (score 0):

You have temp under `main` json object, but you are trying to get directly, change below code:

```
String temp = obj.getString("temp");
```

To like this:

```
JSOnObject main = obj.getJSONObject("main");
String temp = main.getString("temp");
System.out.println("The current temperature is -"+temp);
```

This will work.

Comment: Can also use `JSONArray` here to do something like `JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("main");` and then `results.getString("temp");`

Comment: @px06 no that would not work because main is not a JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

Change main.getString to main.getDouble because temprature is double type.

```
JSONObject main = obj.getJSONObject("main");
String temp = main.getDouble("temp");
System.out.println("Current temprature"+temp);
```